# PHP Code Wrapper

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started learning PHP. I watched a tutorial about building a theme in WordPress using PHP. I want to ask about the term "wrapper", as I know that a wrapper for PHP code is `<?php ?>`. First please look at this code:

```
<?php
        $lastBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1');

        if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):

        while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>


        <?php endwhile;

    endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

and this

```
<?php 
        $lastBlog = new WP_Query('type=post&posts_per_page=1');

        if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):

        while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); 

            get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); 


        endwhile;

    endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

There is a little difference in the way the wrappers used. I'm confused, which is better? Both are running the same way. Sorry if this question looks ridiculous.

I have searched for this topic, and I didn't answer to my question. Is it correct to say "wrapper" instead of "limiter"?

Comment: Both are correct. The first snipped is used more often in wordpress.

Comment: You shouldn't call the opening and closing tags wrappers at all. Because when you do so, you'll be confusing others that are thinking about object oriented wrappers.




Look at these: 






1- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper

.




2- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function

.




3- https://www.ionos.ca/digitalguide/websites/web-development/what-is-a-wrapper

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) calls them *opening and closing tags*:

> When PHP parses a file, it looks for opening and closing tags, which
>   are `<?php` and `?>` which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the
>   code between them. Parsing in this manner allows PHP to be embedded in
>   all sorts of different documents, as everything outside of a pair of
>   opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser.

A *"code wrapper"* is usually understood as a class, or a library, which [encapsulates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) a number of lower-level operations under a simplified programming interface. For example, the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is also known as *wrapper*, since the idea is to create a class that will add extra functionality to another class without changing structures of the other classes.

**Example Wrapper (Decorator)**

```
<?php
class Rectangle {
  private $width, $height;

  public function __construct($w, $h) {
    $this->width = $w;
    $this->height = $h;
  }

  public function getArea() { return $this->width * $this->height; }
  public function getWidth() { return $this->width; }
  public function getHeight() { return $this->height; }
}

// Decorator
class ImprovedRectangle {
  protected $rect;

  public function __construct(Rectangle $r) {
    $this->rect = $r;
  }

  public function getPerimeter() {
    return 2 * ($this->rect->getWidth() + $this->rect->getHeight());
  }
}

$rect = new Rectangle(2, 3);
$irect = new ImprovedRectangle($rect);
echo $irect->getPerimeter(); // 10
```

So it depends on context. If we are speaking about a template code, where the markup code is the major, it is quite correct to call the PHP tags "PHP wrappers". But in the context of a PHP model (a class, or a set of functions), the PHP tags (usually only the opening tag) are mandatory, and we primarily focus on the code constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside the start tag `<?php` and the end tag `?>` will be processed by the PHP processor. I have heard these called *PHP Islands*.Since in the example with more start and end tags there is not  code outside the `<?php ?>` *islands* the code runs the same. Were you to put code outside the *islands* it would be printed as plain text and not sent to the PHP process.

In your example it doesn't make a difference but for readability I would only have one set of `<?php ?>` tags.